# Converting 3D Max Model to XAML?

Tags: wpf, xaml, model

Are there any free tools for converting a 3D Max model to WPF XAML?

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out the Xaml exporter for 3D Max!
http://max2xaml.codeplex.com/

Microsoft blog article explaining it more:
http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/maxim/archive/2009/03/31/daily-tip-how-to-import-3d-model-to-wpf-from-3d-max.aspx

Comment: Thank you, it is a great tool!

Answer (score 1):

U can use blender and max2xaml. Both can help u.